# Android: Cordova background auto sync

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I want my app to run some code in background once a day or 2 time, is there any plugin for this, like IOS we have bachground-fetch.

thank you

Comment: Or you can write your own using `alarmmanager` or `JobScheduler`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this plugin [background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-plugin-background-fetch).